# How can I export the root and intermediate signing certificates from a certificate file via PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate2

Using PowerShell; I need to take a certificate file (.cer/.crt), and export the intermediate and root signing certificate files to the same directory. The most I am able to do is get the certificates Issuer Name (the intermediate CA). How can I leverage PowerShell to determine the intermediate and root signing CAs and save those certificates?

```
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 D:\Netscaler_Certificates\example.2021.cer
$cert.IssuerName
```

gives me:

```
Name                                   Oid                                RawData            
----                                   ---                                -------            
CN=Subordinate CA, DC=domain, DC=com   System.Security.Cryptography.Oid   {48, 99, 49...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build the certificate chain and then export chain elements:

```
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 D:\Netscaler_Certificates\example.2021.cer
$chain = new-object security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain
[void]$chain.Build($cert)
$chain.ChainElements | %{
    sc -path .\$($_.Certificate.GetNameInfo("dnsName",$false)).cer -value $_.Certificate.RawData -encoding byte
}
```

Answer (score 0):

....and to "host out" what certificates you just exported from previous answer, next line could be:

```
(($chain.ChainElements.Certificate.Subject | Select-Object -Skip 1) -Replace ", .*").trimstart("CN=")
```